# determining if two events are independent or not

Tags: probability

The set up for the question is:
A hand of five cards is dealt - randomly, one card at a time, and without replacement - from each of two standard decks of 52 cards.

the question:
Determine whether the events of "two hands have at least one card in common" and "the first hand is all hearts" are independent or not.

My thinking is that they are independent of each other. This is because if there is a hand full of hearts, at least one card may come up in common. Alternatively, if there is not a hand full of hands, this may also occur.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, or not, and if there is any way for me to prove this theory.

Comment: The argument you give here is not correct. All you have shown is that the events are not mutually exclusive. In order to show that they are independent you must decide if the probability of having at least one card in common depends on whether the other hand has five hearts or not. See @Y.H.'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are independent, since for a general hand of five, you can always relabel them by five  hearts. (In math language, to construct a permutation on the set {1,2,...,52}, such that five cards you have chosen are mapped into the 13-element subset representing hearts.) Hence knowing the first hand has 5 hearts does not give you any information.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Is there any way of showing this through calculations or is it just a verbal explanation?

Comment: In this case, what I prefer to do is to translate my intuition into rigorous language. Let B={two hands intersect}, S be a 5-element subset of {1,...,52}. Then you can show P(B|first hand=S) is independent of the choice of S, by expressing it in terms of binomial coefficient.

Comment: For more clarification on the setup, you mean drawing a hand of five from EACH of the two decks, right?

Comment: yes, from each. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Events $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A|B)=P(A)$ (see e.g. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29)).

In words: whether you already know that $B$ is true or not makes no difference for the probability on $A$.

Now, suppose you already know there is a common card, then the probability the hand is all hearts has become zero. That is different from the normal chance of a hand full of hearts.

Therefore, the hands are *not* independent.